# ERROR TableInputFormat: Java.lang.NullPointerException at org.Apache.Hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to read data from HBase using Spark. Versions I'm using is
 Spark 1.3.1 and Hbase 1.1.1. I am getting following error

```
ERROR TableInputFormat: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                              
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf(TableName.java:417)                                                              
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:159)                                                              
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.setConf(TableInputFormat.java:101)                                      
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:91)                                                     
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)                                                        
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)                                                        
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)                                                                                   
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)                                                                         
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)                                             
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)                                                        
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)                                                        
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)                                                                                   
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)                                                                         
    at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:82)                                                             
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.getDependencies(ShuffledRDD.scala:80)                                                     
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:206)                                                      
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)                                                      
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)                                                                                   
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.dependencies(RDD.scala:204)                                                                       
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scal
```

The code is as follows

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String TABLE_NAME = "Hello";
    HTable table=null;
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    sparkConf.setAppName("Data Reader").setMaster("local[1]");
    sparkConf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "$(hbase classpath)");

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    Configuration hbConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hbConf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
    try {
         table = new HTable(hbConf, Bytes.toBytes(TABLE_NAME));

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD = sparkContext
            .newAPIHadoopRDD(
                    hbConf,
                    TableInputFormat.class,
                    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class);
    hBaseRDD.coalesce(1, true);
    System.out.println("Count "+hBaseRDD.count());
    //.saveAsTextFile("hBaseRDD");
    try {
        table.close();
        sparkContext.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am not able to resolve the Issue. I am using Hortonworks Sandbox for this.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @SimonePessotto   please check edited post

Comment: wich version of the java API are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have write:

```
try {
     table = new HTable(hbConf, Bytes.toBytes(TABLE_NAME));

} catch (IOException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

IF YOU'RE USING 1.1.1 api:

In the [devapidocs](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/index.html) I can see only two constructor:

> protected **HTable(ClusterConnection conn, BufferedMutatorParams params)**
>   For internal testing.
>
> protected **HTable(TableName tableName, ClusterConnection connection,
>   TableConfiguration tableConfig, RpcRetryingCallerFactory
>   rpcCallerFactory, RpcControllerFactory rpcControllerFactory,
>   ExecutorService pool)** Creates an object to access a HBase table.

The constructor of params for the first constructor is:  `BufferedMutatorParams(TableName tableName)`

and TableName has no constructor.

So you have to initialize your HTable like this:

```
table = new HTable(hbConf, new bufferedMutatorParams(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME))
```

IF YOU'RE USING [0.94 API](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html):

The constructors of HTBale are:

> HTable(byte[] tableName, HConnection connection) Creates an object to
>   access a HBase table. HTable(byte[] tableName, HConnection connection,
>   ExecutorService pool) Creates an object to access a HBase table.
>
> HTable(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf, byte[] tableName)
>   Creates an object to access a HBase table.
>
> **HTable(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf, byte[] tableName,
>   ExecutorService pool)** Creates an object to access a HBase table.
>
> **HTable(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf, String tableName)**
>   Creates an object to access a HBase table.

So, look ath the last, you need only to pass the String name not the bytes[]

```
table = new HTable(hbConf, TABLE_NAME);
```

it should be ok.